# No such file or directory : var/www/html in ec2 instance

Tags: html, mysql, linux, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I just setup an amazon instance on EC2, and would like to install phpmyadmin and mysql on my server. I can successfully SSH to my ec2-user account and display the folders.

I am following this tutorial here to get phpmyadmin installed, but I am stuck on the first point itself where its asking me to redirect to the html folder via var/www/html.

I can locate the var folder, but the www/html folders are there at all. Is there anything im missing that I should be doing? Please do let me know if there was meant to be any other call that i was supposed to carry out other than the sudo yum phpmyadmin command. 
Thank you

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 3):

Do you already have a web server like Nginx / Apache running? If not you may want to install one first, along with PHP as this should set up the directory structure.

If you do then you can just use the 'mkdir' command to create these directories as required and then modify your web server configuration to point to /var/www/html

For example with Apache, my configuration in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName test
</VirtualHost>
```

Essentially the specific directory shouldn't really matter too much as you can select which one to use in the configuration, /var/www/html is just considered a default location.

Comment: Just found that that I needed to install php so that it will create those html folders naturally
Update your answer and ill give it to you :)